# Replacing cryptico.js with WebCryptoAPI - how do I get Public Key string?

Tags: javascript, public-key-encryption, webcrypto-api, cryptico

I hope someone can help.
I have been using cryptico.js and have been generating keys via:

```
var RSAkey = cryptico.generateRSAKey(passphrase, 512);
var publicKeyString = cryptico.publicKeyString(RSAkey);
```

Giving me clean good access to a public key, like: `vnY5f+HVUQa2oBZKsb2LUgTlso/wtVsA5Ytqlr1RL13xVN81mnIHoL/5/8CKG4rQ/vQfnBAUBYfJzBQGeAXYnw==`

I am switching to use WebCrypto API as I want to use a different key type:

```
promise_key = crypto.subtle.generateKey({name: "ECDSA", namedCurve: "P-256", hash: {name: "SHA-256"} }, true, ["sign", "verify"]);
promise_key.then(function(key) {
    private_key_object = key.privateKey;
    public_key_object = key.publicKey;
    console.log(key.publicKey);
});
```

I am wanting to get the Public Key String as I do with cryptico, and I am sure I am doing something very silly but I can't seem to get it.

I have used `crypto.subtle.exportKey` with 'spki', 'raw' and 'jwk' options but no joy.

Even if I use RSA to generate keys instead of ECDSA, I still get the same.

What am I doing wrong, please?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The `CryptoKey` itself is not viewable via a simple `console.log`. It first needs to be transformed into the desired format. You can use [exportKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/exportKey) for that (as long as you have set `extractable` to `true - which you did).

[Here are some examples.](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples)